# A doubt regarding integration.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have two functions: 
$F=6t$ and $x=t^3/3$

I want to find the integral over $t$ from $0$ to $4$.

I am a beginner at integration, so I converted $F$ in terms of $x$  i.e. $6\, (3x)^{1/3}$
  and integrated it from $x=64/3$ to $x=0$ (I did this by putting t=4 in the eq. of $x$). The answer was $384$.

What's bothering me is that, when i converted $x$ in terms of $F$ i.e. $(F/6)^3\times 1/3$  and integrated it over from $F=24$ to $F=0$ (I did this by putting $t=4$ in the eq. of $F$). I got $128$.

What I am not getting is why are the answers different?

Comment: So you want to integrate with respect to $x$ or $t$?

Comment: With respect to t

Comment: Are you sure? What's the point of $x$ then?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I misunderstood. I want to integrate it with respect to x. Also is it equivalent of integrating x with respect to F? I am confused between the two.

Comment: That is why we have notation with $dx$ or $dt$ in it.  $\int_0^4 6t\;dt \ne \int_0^4 6t\;dx$.  Once you write it properly, we will know what you mean.

Comment: I know that I am confused that is integration of x with respect to F equivalent to integration of F with respect to x with proper limits?

Comment: Are you calculating work done? $\int F\cdot dx$ ? use mathjax for formatting, its really easy. [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Oh yes I am calculating work done.

Comment: The answers are different because $\int_{0}^{4^3/3} F\mathsf d x$ and $\int_{0}^{24} x\mathsf d F$ are very different things.

Comment: But why are they different? In an another example, I got same answers, with two other functions.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Because $x\tfrac{\mathsf d F}{\mathsf d x}$ is *very rarely* going to equal $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $F(t)=6t$ and $x(t)=t^3/3 \implies F(x)=6(3x)^{1/3}$ and $x(F)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{F}{6}\right)^3$

Your question says that you need to calculate (correct me if I'm wrong), which you did and got as $$\int_{x(0)=0}^{x(4)=\frac{64}{3}}F \cdot\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{\frac{64}{3}}6(3x)^{1/3}\mathrm{d}x=384 \tag{1}$$

Next you did, because you wanted to integrate with respect to $F$ this time, 
$$\int_{F(0)=0}^{F(4)=24}x \cdot\mathrm{d}F=\int_{0}^{24}\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{F}{6}\right)^3\mathrm{d}F=128 \tag{2}$$

Okay, now look at $(1)$, if you want to integrate with respect to $F$, you will have to use *change of variables* from $x$ to $F$. Since you know $$x = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{F}{6}\right)^3 \implies \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}F}=\frac{F^2}{216} \implies \mathrm{d}x = \frac{F^2}{216} \mathrm{d}F$$
So from $(1)$, you have
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{64}{3}}F \cdot\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{24}F\cdot\frac{F^2}{216} \mathrm{d}F=\int_{0}^{24}\left(\frac{F}{6}\right)^3\mathrm{d}F \tag{3}$$

Well, as we know $(1)=(3)$, but clearly $(3) \neq (2)$. I hope you can now see where you went wrong

Comment: I am really thankful to you. So the thing I was missing was that we cannot directly substitute and change the variables during integration.